# Find numbers in the groups using the sum and number of items in groups

Tags: algorithm, recursion, sum

I have 50 distinct integer numbers. A person has divided them into groups and has shown me the sum of numbers in each group and the number of items in each group. I want to find the numbers in the groups. If I use a recursive brute-force C++ program to find them, it takes too long for me. I want a more efficient way to find them.

Comment: Start trying with greedy algorithm.

Comment: The KNAPSACK problem is NP-complete; I'd be greatly-suprised if you could find a fast way to do this.

Comment: Side note - While brute force may be too slow regardless, iterative brute force is a way better idea than recursive brute force. And start with the group with the least elements or the one with the lowest sum.

Comment: If there is no other constraint on the numbers, there are an infinite number of possible solutions and it would be very easy to construct the numbers in each group given the sum and number for each.

Comment: @mbratch ... except when all the groups have size 1, in which case a solution (or determining solvability) is trivial.

Comment: What kind of constraint may help the solution. I only know that any two near numbes have more chance to be in the same group, while it is only a hint for me and not a rule.

Comment: @mbratch We seem to have missed that the task is "I have 50 distinct integer numbers" not "Find 50 distinct integer numbers".

Comment: Yes, but we don't know what they are. We only know the constraints. So we have to find them. :)

Comment: @mbratch Well, if there's only 50 numbers to pick from, it means that there aren't infinitely many solutions, and the expected running time (by my guess) is somewhere in the region of O(50!), which is ... a lot, but not infinite. It's a lot like the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Answer (score 0):

A naive recursive solution can be boosted in running time by pruning.

Can you post your code?
Once you post your code, I will edit this answer to show you how.